# Laravel - Differences between two solutions of a method in a controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

A stack overflow user answered me two ways to return each person's furniture in a 'one to many' relationship. This worked well.

My question is to know the difference in the two ways. The advantages and disadvantages of each way.

**IMPORTANT**: Laravel Version: 5.8

**First solution:**

```
public function showPersonFurnitures($id) {
    $person = Person::with('furnitures')->findOrFail($id);     
    $furnituresOfEachPerson = $person->furnitures; //<-----
    
    return response()->json($furnituresOfEachPerson);     
}
```

**Second solution:**

```
public function showPersonFurnitures($id) {
    $person = Person::with('furnitures')->findOrFail($id);     
    $furnituresOfEachPerson = $person->furnitures()->get(); //<----
    
    return response()->json($furnituresOfEachPerson);      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given answers are vague and incomplete, so here's a better explanation hopefully:

**Situation 1 `$person->furnitures()`:** When you call any of a model's relations as a *function*, you get an (incomplete) query object for that particular relation. That means whenever you call `$person->furnitures()`, any additional functions you chain on this result like `->where()` are actual SQL operators and directly modify the query. In order to complete the query, you *should* call `->get()` (or a function like `->pluck()`) at the end to retrieve the actual data.

**Situation 2 `$person->furnitures`:** When you call any of a model's relations as a *property*, you retrieve the complete relation collection for that model. This means that `$person->furnitures` lazy-loads the collection if it is not available on the model yet. Any additional functions you chain on this result like `->where()` will act on the PHP collection.

---

By using `Person::with('furnitures')...` you make sure that the relation is already loaded ([Eager Loaded](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)) after the `findOrFail()` call. You might note that this is not particularly useful with respect to loading 1 model (since you might just as well call `$person->furnitures` whenever you need it), but the important thing to remember here is that this [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method is extremely useful when you are retrieving collections of a model, like `$persons = Person::where('activated', 1)->with('furnitures')->get()`. This last query only executes 2 queries: 1 for retrieving persons, and 1 for retrieving all furniture related to these persons.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, the difference for those 2 methods are not huge and you will get the same result, except:

- `$person->furnitures` uses relationships, quite similar to [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) that it retrieves data based on the One to Many relationship.
- `$person->furnitures()->get()` is implemented from the perspective of collection, which is why it has the syntax of querying a collection.

Answer (score 0):

They are same, but `$person->furnitures` requires extra steps to understand tha this is relation, and finally call `$person->furnitures()->get()`

Comment: How is this 2 lines explanation badly worded good for anyone ?

Comment: I answered earlier than this user why his answer is accepted not mine